# How to fast-forward replacing submodule with it's files in Git?

Tags: git, git-submodules, fast-forward

Git aborts merge when I try to git pull a commit (or set of commits) which do the following:

1. Remove a submodule located at a subdirectory
2. Add the submodule's contents at the subdirectory (different files, same file names)

I have no merge conflicts if I split this into separate git pulls for each action. This is problematic though, because other users can't compile the project until they git pull the second commit which I cannot push as long as someone hasn't pulled the first commit.

Is there a way to fast-forward such change in Git?

UPDATE:

This is my repository structure:

```
|-- Common
|-- Components
|-- Lib
|-- Projects
|   |-- main_project
|   |   |-- some_binary
|   |   |-- some_other_binary
|   |   |-- Sources
|   |   |   |-- SUBMODULE_IS_HERE
|   |   |   |   |-- many_submodule_files.here
|   |   |   |-- files.here
|   |-- other_project
|   |-- other_project_2
|-- Resources
|-- .gitignore
|-- .gitmodules
```

These are the commands I execute from a local repository:

```
mv Projects/main_project/Sources/SUBMODULE_IS_HERE SUBMODULE_IS_HERE_tmp

git submodule deinit -f -- Projects/main_project/Sources/SUBMODULE_IS_HERE
rm -rf .git/modules/Projects/main_project/Sources/SUBMODULE_IS_HERE
git rm -rf Projects/main_project/Sources/SUBMODULE_IS_HERE
git rm .gitmodules
git commit -m "Removed submodule"
git push origin master

rm -rf SUBMODULE_IS_HERE_tmp/.git
rm SUBMODULE_IS_HERE_tmp/.gitignore
mv SUBMODULE_IS_HERE_tmp Projects/main_project/Sources/SUBMODULE_IS_HERE
git add .
git commit -m "Added submodule code back into main repository"
git push origin master
```

Now, this is the state of a different local repository (e.g. coworker's)

```
$ git log --graph --oneline --all
* e8d95d3ec (origin/master, origin/HEAD) Added submodule code back into main repository
* 9a2fc256b Removed submodule
* 31aeff6da (HEAD -> master) fixed bug #4442
```

And now the coworker tries to git pull both commits:

```
$ git pull origin master
From X:/repo-TEST
 * branch                master     -> FETCH_HEAD
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
        Projects/main_project/Sources/SUBMODULE_IS_HERE/many_files.here
        Projects/main_project/Sources
Aborting
Updating 31aeff6da..e8d95d3ec
```

What I mean by "two separate git pulls" is when my coworker pulls the first commit which removes the submodule. This causes no problems. After that, I push the second commit, which adds back the files into main repository. Finally, they pull the second commit. Once again, there are no problems.

Why does this work "in two git pulls" as explained in paragraph above and does not work with a one git pull?

Is there anything I can do to make this work in one git pull?

Comment: Please update your question with the repo structure and state (both local and remote) and the commands you try to run. I have 2 misundertandings with your question: 1) "separate git pulls". So git pull is git fetch + git merge. Normally it is a single action, I can't imagine "separate pulls". 2) "I cannot push as long as someone hasn't pulled the first commit" - this is also impossible with git, as it doesn't track what other people have or haven't pulled. What matters is your local state and the remote branch state (where you push to).

Comment: `...which I cannot push as long as someone hasn't pulled the first commit.` Why?

Comment: @battlmonstr Updated my question. I hope it's better now.

Comment: It is clear now, but I don't know the answer. It feels that while the pull is removing the submodule on the co-worker's computer he has to manually delete the (now untracked) files. If the pull command is not able to do that, that error is inevitable. One workaround would be to use a new folder name for the converted submodule (e.g. "Vendor"), and then have some grace period until everyone updates, and so rename "Vendor" back to "Sources".